# Jsp file couldnt view using spring boot mvc

Tags: spring-boot

I'm created spring mvc pattern using jsp.But when I call the route jsp contains not display

my project jsp file path is

```
 src/main/resources/META-INF/webapp/WEB-INF.jsp/jsp/Helloworld.jsp
```

my index controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
@GetMapping("/helloworld")
String getView(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("msg", "Hello there");
 System.out.printf("test hello world ..................");
 return "Helloworld";
}
}
```

***my Helloworld.jsp***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <h2>${msg}</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
welcome.message:helloworld
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When i call the route

```
localhost:8000/hellworld
```

then system.out.println message is appear in terminal but in the web nothing display.
can you help me ?

Comment: what the error msg its showing

Comment: WEB-INF/jsp  are server side components. You should not put them under the resource folder. Move your web-inf folder under the main folder. Resource folder is for static components only

Comment: @harkeshkumar there are no errors.

Comment: @georgesvan i already tried but not work

Comment: do you have a blank page or what do you see ?

Comment: @georgesvan blank page

Comment: Not sure whish port u are using but add this server.port = 8000 to your application.properties

Comment: can take a screenshot of your project structure

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then make sure you are the right port by adding the following to your `server.port = 8000` to your `application.properties`

Finally run `http://localhost:8000/helloworld`  instead of `localhost:8000/hellworld`

Your jsp page should looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello ${msg}!</title>

</head>
<body>
   <h2 >Hello ${msg}!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```